# How Can I change database value according to comming link

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arduino, nodemcu

I don't know how to tell but I will try :)

I am using NodeMCU and CAM module, CAM module read the QR code and user 1 get the link like this: sitename.com/project/userid1

For example another user 2 have sitename.com/project/userid2 link. And CAM module send to link by string to the NODEMCU I did this step.

NODEMCU can connect this link to the internet.
Main question is how can I do this:

When the user logs in from a specific address for example user 1 get sitename.com/project/userid1 link. How to reduce the balance of user1 (defined in the database)?
So I can do a transaction in the database with the information I came from any link. How can the site know how I come from that link ?

Please help me.

**EDIT 1**

I decide to send just ID  for user, for the userid1 send to 1, userid2 send to 2 ... When I get the "1" I want to go ID=1 user and get the user1's balance.

So, that's the new question. When I connect with nodemcu to MYSQL, how can I get the balance value (this is table users' member) and how to send balance=balance-1  value to MYSQL ?

How to add this code to arduino

```
 UPDATE users SET balance=balance_new WHERE id = readx

readx come 1,2,3,.. to the CAM module
users name the mysql table 
balance is the member of the users
```

This is my some code: (How can add part of mysql get value and send value)

```
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
int balance;

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "pas";
IPAddress server_addr(xx, xx ,xx, x);          // MySQL server IP
char user[] = "sitename_user";           // MySQL user
char password[] = "pass";       // MySQL password
void setup () {

Serial.begin(19200);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

delay(1000);
Serial.print("Connecting..");

}

 while (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password) != true) {
    delay(200);
    Serial.println("Connecting SQL..");

  }
      Serial.println("Connected SQL..");


}

void loop() {
 if(Serial.available()>0)    //Checks is there any data in buffer 
  {
    String readx=Serial.readString();
    Serial.print(readx);  //Read serial data byte and send back to serial monitor

if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status
//Get the request response payload



HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient

http.begin(readx);  //Specify request destination
int httpCode = http.GET();                                                                  //Send the request

if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code

String payload = http.getString(); 
                //Print the response payload

}

http.end();   //Close connection

}
  }

delay(30000);    //Send a request every 30 seconds

}
```

Comment: Update my question !